# Gradle: 'Cannot do operations on a non-existent table' with Local Dynamodb

Tags: java, gradle, amazon-dynamodb

I have a desktop web app in Java that builds and runs with two Dynamodb tables, and somehow one of the tables (Customers) was created but the other (FoodItems) was not. When I try to access FoodItems via the API, I get an exception: `Cannot do operations on a non-existent table`. When I try to access FoodItems during a JUnit test, same thing: `BUILD FAIL com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException`.

I know why. It's because the FoodItems table is never created. But I cannot figure out where or how to create it, and I'm not even sure how the Customers table was created in the first place.

I'm using this [git repository](https://github.com/KonstantinTsykulenko/java-dynamodb-demo) from [this tutorial](https://tech.smartling.com/getting-started-with-amazon-dynamodb-and-java-universal-language-850fa1c8a902#.thlj6eamy). I have just duplicated the classes and JUnit tests to add a FoodItems table. The project builds just fine, but if I go to `http://localhost:8080/fooditems`, I get the exception above...It happens specifically at the line `foodItemRepository.save(fooditem);` in JUnit test.

How do I create a table when the app starts if the table doesn't yet exist?

Answer (score 1):

I had created an interface for DBInitializer that would allow me to create abstract classes like CustomerDBInitializer, FoodItemDBInitializer, etc. This was causing the problem. I believe the root cause was because I was using Spring and @PostConstruct annotators with an interface.